# Cannot connecting texture to heightmap using mapped uniform location

Tags: opengl, c++, heightmap

In my shader program, I have my attributes and uniforms added to a map for each. What I have displayed is a heightmap, but cant seem to connect the graphic texture to display.

`mUniformList` *(std::string, GLuint)* contains all the uniforms added from my shader (8 total). The problem is that retrieving and connecting the sampler2D named "groundTexture."

```
void Terrain::init()
{
    ....
    ....

    // VAO 
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &mVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(mVAO);

    // VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &mVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mVertices), &mVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["position"]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader["position"], 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // IBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &mIBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mIBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mIndices), &mIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Load Heightmap texture
    mTexture.loadTexture(heightMapFilePath, mHeightMapTextureID, 0);

    // Texture coordinates
    glGenBuffers(1, &mTexCoordID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mTexCoordID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(mTexCoords), &mTexCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shader["texCoord"]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shader["texCoord"], 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    // load ground texture
    mTexture.loadTexture(groundTextureFilePath, mTextureID, 0);

    shader.connectTexture(mTextureID);
}
```

With connectTexture being:

```
void TerrainShader::connectTexture(GLuint id)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glUniform1i(mUniformList["backgroundTexture"], 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Fixed dereferencable error pertaining to the `mUniformList`. No errors of any kind whatsoever, but still nothing displayed.

**terrainfrag.glsl**

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

smooth in vec2 TexCoord;
smooth in vec3 Normal;

uniform sampler2D backgroundTexture;

void main()
{
    vec3 normalized = normalize(Normal);

    color = texture(backgroundTexture, TexCoord);
    color += vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the variable declarations of the vertex shader as-well?

Comment: The only thing pertaining to my problem in my vertex shader is passing the texCoord from there to the fragment shader.

Comment: You have `color += vec4(1,1,1,1);` is that meant to be there just to see the terrain white for the bottom image?

Comment: Yes its just for showing that the heightmap is actually there

Comment: This might be more relevant to Computer Graphics StackExchange

Answer (score 1):

To be able to debug OpenGL errors I highly suggest you use a `CheckGLError` function to check for errors after OpenGL calls.

My assumption is that you are getting an OpenGL error before your call to connectTexture. I believe that error is because you are not setting a proper offset when passing texCoord data to OpenGL. When you are setting 0 as the offset, and passing `vec2` instead of the expected `vec3` for `position`.  You want to have an `offset` for the texCoords.  *(With the assumption that position is at location 0, and texCoords are at location 1)*

To load a model with texture coordinates into OpenGL you want to use code similar to this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(shader.texCoord, // index
                      2,               // size [ Use 4 if you can ]
                      GL_FLOAT,        // type
                      GL_FALSE,        // normalized
                      bytesInOneVertex,// stride [ sizeof( Vertex_p3t2 ) ]
                      (GLvoid*)byteOffsetToUVCoords );  // You are missing this?
// Check for OpenGL error
```

To send a texture to your glsl shader you want to use code similar to this:

```
glActiveTexture(texNameID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
glUniform1i(textureUniformLocation, texID/*-1*/); // might need to -1 for proper id.
// Check for OpenGL error
```

**For future consideration**

Using `shader["..."]` and `find("....")` uses a string comparision which will take up a lot of computation time and will slow your program down when you start to have a lot more calls to it.  I suggest you change it to direct variables from an array or object instead.

Also I suggest to take advantage of OpenGL by passing vertices of size 4 instead of 3 or 2.

**Resources**

glVertexAttribPointer: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml
CheckGLError: [glDrawElements Crash](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111933/gldrawelements-crash/111936#111936)

**UPDATE**

In your connectTexture method try changing it to `glUniform1i(mUniformList["backgroundTexture"], id);`.  Also try `id-1` if that doesn't work.  Your texture id's start at 1, and 2.  So if it is using "2" it won't be reading it from "0".

**Edit #2**
Here is more detailed code for your reference:
[Terrain shader from heightmap opengl GLSL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111875/terrain-shader-from-heightmap-opengl-glsl/111886#111886)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was calling mUniform the wrong way in the connectTexture function. Furthermore, I dont have any gl errors flagging. My vertices, indices and texCoords are stored separately, so there is no need for stride. I even converted my array of vec2 texture coords into a single float array, but nothing happened. My first guess is that something has to do with the connectTexture function. my heightmapTexture location has a value of 0, where my backgroundTexture location has a value of 7. Dont know if that means much of anything.